# Size of the root node of a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE, the root of the tree seems to be an empty node, but I can't find a way to cancel its size, so the two branches are not connected.

I'm sure there is a simple way to solve this, but after some search, I was unable to find one (minimum height and others don't do the trick).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=2cm,sibling distance=1.5cm}]
    \node{} [grow' =right]
    child {node {$S$} edge from parent node[above]{$p$}}
    child {node {$E$} edge from parent node[below]{$q$}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a `coordinate` to "cancel its size". (It looks a bit better with `line cap=round`, otherwise you could make the node a tiny dot.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=2cm,sibling
  distance=1.5cm},line cap=round]
    \node[coordinate]{} [grow' =right]
    child {node {$S$} edge from parent node[above]{$p$}}
    child {node {$E$} edge from parent node[below]{$q$}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) Exactly what I was looking for !